# How to write Applescript to press Escape key?

Tags: macos, applescript

I am writing an apple-script.

In which I need to write code which means to hit escape button.

I'm not getting how to do it.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

simple,

```
tell application "System Events"
     key code 53
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple thing.. Its such a silly thing man.. shye.. anyways.. thnks alot.. :-)

Comment: Be sure to use `key code` and not `keystroke`. I made that mistake. :)

Comment: Where can I find a translation of keys to key codes?

Comment: this is a great resource https://danielabaron.me/blog/automate-keyboard-mac/#1-scripteditor